# Refactoring my shell scipts : calling a script and redirect output to a new file inside a loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that uses the sed command to transform an input file to a new output file, this script works when I call :

```
./sed_command.sh input_file > output_file
```

here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while read line
  do
    # Split each line based on ; separator
    transposed=$(echo "$line" | sed -e "s/;/\\n/g")
    res=$(echo "$transposed" | sed '/${GDATEF(\([^,]*\),ddMMyyyy)}/{
            # Split the string in two part
            s//\1/g
            # # parse the input for GNU date input format
            s/D/ day/g
            # Handle shell quoting
            '"s/'/\\''\\'/"'
             # pass and execute date
            s/.*/date -d "now "'\''&'\'' +%d%m%Y/e
        }')
    oneline=$(echo "$res" | sed -z "s/\n/;/g" | sed 's/.$//')
    echo $oneline
  done < $1
```

Now I need to call that script inside a double loop that browse all directories in a folder :

```
cd /etc/newman/Newman

for team in *;do
      if  [ -d "$team" ]; then
          echo "team=$team"
          cd $team
          for scope in *;do
              if [ -d "$scope" ]; then
                  echo "scope=$scope"
                  CSV_FILE=$(ls /etc/newman/Newman/$team/$scope/*.csv -1  || true)
                  echo "Transforming : ${CSV_FILE}"
                  if [ ! -z "${CSV_FILE}" ] ; then sh sed_command.sh  ${CSV_FILE} > ${CSV_FILE}_Newman; else echo "No CSV files to transform"; fi


              fi
          done
          cd ..
      fi
    done
```

I have tested the second script looping works fine the only issue is when I call sed_command.sh inside the second script I get theses two errors :

```
: not found.sh: line 2:
sed_command.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected "done" (expecting "do")
```

I guess redirection does not work the same way inside a loop? thanks for help

Comment: Your script seems to have dos line endings. Remove them. Also, as noted before, check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: I have applied dos2unix to myscripts and the error is still there, regarding shellcheck even though it seems to bundled with ShellScript plugin I could not se the path to its exec file as it does not exist in my plugin folders!  I have a community version of IntelliJ

Comment: `: not found.sh: line 2:` definitely looks like a CR character. What would `./sed_command.sh 2>&1 | hexdump -C` output? `I could not se the path t` Nowadays, stuiff is available online https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks I have shellchecked my files now I don't have any warning. As I am locally on windows I don't have hexdump locally, my shell is meant to be run don centos based docker container so I have tested it first on windows :  ./sed_command.sh ImportDocumentsCreate.csv > output.csv it works. Then I have copied it to docker, run dos2unix then tried the same command : it ouputs sed help text!!! same if I add hexdump -C

Comment: `Then I have copied it to docker` As noted, `/e` is a GNU sed extension and is discouraged. When you use extensions, you can't expect your command to work everywhere. Do not use them, or install GNU sed. Strongly consider using a real programming language - python, perl are examples.

Comment: I guess that's the problem  indeed as it looks that sed in my docker does not have that option here is the error:                                                                                                         
sed: bad option in substitution expression
sed: unrecognized option: z
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary. I don't have the possibility of using python this is a restriction I have so I need to make it work without e option.

Comment: Okay as I have spent dew days on that I will give it a try I need to avoid using -z for -e I resolved it. if it does not working I will use perl , thanks for your help .

Comment: Your sed usage is a mystery to me. What do you expect from `/${GDATEF.../`? And from `s//\1/g`? Could you explain what you are trying to do to your input file? And also show an example input file plus the expected output? There are chances that somebody will propose a much simpler and working solution.

Comment: What's the point of the `ls ....` command? Why don't you simply do a `echo /etc/newman/Newman/$team/$scope/*.csv` at this place? In any case will you run into problems if there is more than one csv file present, or when `team` or `scope` contain a space.

Comment: Why don't you turn on `-x`, at least for those lines which produce the error?

Comment: A much simpler way to loop over all these files would be `for f in */*/*.csv; do sed_command.sh "$f" > "${f}_Newman"; done`.